.net maui 'Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.'
Using .net maui and the mvvm community toolkit, we're doing a basic account registration page that should work the same across platforms.
As part of the flow we want to (asynchronously) check if the username already exists. To do this we've added the UserStoppedTypingBehaviour to the username entry field
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="{AppThemeBinding Light=user_icon.png, Dark=user_icon_dark.png}" Style="{StaticResource EntryIcon}" />
        <Entry x:Name="UserNameEntry" Text="{Binding Username}" Placeholder="User name"
               IsEnabled="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={helpers:InverseBoolConverter}}" Style="{StaticResource Default}">
            <Entry.Behaviors>
                <toolkit:UserStoppedTypingBehavior 
                    Command="{Binding UsernameCheckCommand}"
                    StoppedTypingTimeThreshold="500"
                    MinimumLengthThreshold="5"/>
                <toolkit:TextValidationBehavior
                    x:Name="UsernameValidator"
                    Flags="ValidateOnValueChanged"
                    MinimumLength="5" MaximumLength="20"
                    IsValid="{Binding UsernameIsValid}"/>
            </Entry.Behaviors>
        </Entry>
    </StackLayout>

And then we've got the following in the viewmodel
    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(RegisterCommand))]
    private string _username;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool _usernameIsValid;

    [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(RegisterCommand))]
    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool _accountExists = false;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _errorMessage;

    private readonly Dictionary<ErrorTypes, string> Errors = [];
    
    .
    .
    .

    [RelayCommand]
    private async Task UsernameCheck()
    {
        AccountExists = false;
        if (UsernameIsValid)
        {
            Errors.Remove(ErrorTypes.AccountExists);
            var accountCheckResponse = await CheckAccountExists();
            if (accountCheckResponse.IsOK)
            {
                AccountExists = accountCheckResponse.Data;
                if (AccountExists)
                {
                    Errors.Add(ErrorTypes.AccountExists, "This username is already taken, please try another.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Errors.Add(ErrorTypes.AccountExists, $"Opps, something went wrong. {accountCheckResponse.Message}.");
            }
        }
        UpdateErrorMessage();
    }

    private async Task<Response<bool>> CheckAccountExists()
    {
        var response = new Response<bool>();
        try
        {
            response = await AccountService.CheckAccountExistsAsync(Username);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response.AddErrorMessage(ex.Message);
        }

        return response;
    }

    private void UpdateErrorMessage()
    {
        ErrorMessage = string.Join(" ", Errors.Values.ToList());
    }

The Response class is just a wrapper for passing around results and corresponding messages.
The AccountService is a library and makes asynchronous calls to a Json RPC endpoint. Every async call within the AccountService uses ConfigureAwait(false).
This code throws the Android 'Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.' for some user entry when executing in an emulator.
This should be really basic and simple, so what are we doing wrong?
Edited to add further details ---->
The exception is occurring during the [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(RegisterCommand))] code.
Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
   .
   .
   .
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Button.Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Internals.ICommandElement.CanExecuteChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Button\Button.cs:line 463
   at CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input.AsyncRelayCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged() in /_/src/CommunityToolkit.Mvvm/Input/AsyncRelayCommand.cs:line 267
   at RewardsApp.ViewModels.RegisterViewModel.set_AccountExists(Boolean value) in C:\BySapio\Starling\DotNet\RewardsApp\CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.SourceGenerators\CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.SourceGenerators.ObservablePropertyGenerator\RewardsApp.ViewModels.RegisterViewModel.g.cs:line 137
   at RewardsApp.ViewModels.RegisterViewModel.UsernameCheck() in C:\BySapio\Starling\DotNet\RewardsApp\ViewModels\RegisterViewModel.cs:line 76

(Note, I've cut out much of the stack trace to focus on the important part.)
The register command definition and related check function are
    private bool CheckCanRegister()
    {
        UpdateErrorMessage();
        return !IsBusy && UsernameIsValid && !AccountExists && PasswordIsValid && Password == ConfirmPassword;
    }

    [RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(CheckCanRegister))]
    public async Task Register()
    {
        .
        .
        .
    }


(I'm not a Maui guy, but...) Take a look at the Dispatcher class. It can be used to marshal (dispatch) call to the thread that owns the view: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.dispatching.dispatcher?view=net-maui-8.0

We had tried having all of the logic in the CheckAccountExists method and then in UsernameCheck just calling Application.Current.Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () => await CheckAccountExists());. This avoided the exception being thrown but seemed to block the UI thread as it introduced a noticeable delay once the UserStoppedTypingBehavior kicked in and prevented the user from continuing with entry in other fields (such as password) while the account existence check was carried out.

Which line of code is the root cause of the exception?

It's occurring within the [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(RegisterCommand))] (community toolkit) code. I've updated the question to add this information.
